# How to set baseurl in protractor tests dynamically based on different spec files?

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, saucelabs

I am working on an Angular application (V9) that serves 2 brands. While writing e2e tests, I am facing a problem. Each brand has a separate url, For instance, brand1: 'https://qa1.brandX.com' and brand2: 'https://qa1.brandY.com'.

Here is the code for protractor.conf.js

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  sauceUser: 'username',
  sauceKey: 'key',
  allScriptsTimeout:20000,
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  multiCapabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      version: 'latest',
      platform: 'Windows 10',
      name: 'chrome test demo',
      'tunnel-identifier': 'getTunnel'',
      /**
       * If this is set to be true, specs will be sharded by file (i.e. all
       * files to be run by this set of capabilities will run in parallel).
       * Default is false.
       */
      shardTestFiles: true,

      /**
       * Maximum number of browser instances that can run in parallel for this
       * set of capabilities. This is only needed if shardTestFiles is true.
       * Default is 1.
       */
      maxInstances: 1,
    },
    {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      version: 'latest',
      platform: 'Windows 10',
      name: 'demo-protractor-jasmine-ts',
      'tunnel-identifier': 'getTunnel',
      /**
       * If this is set to be true, specs will be sharded by file (i.e. all
       * files to be run by this set of capabilities will run in parallel).
       * Default is false.
       */
      shardTestFiles: true,

      /**
       * Maximum number of browser instances that can run in parallel for this
       * set of capabilities. This is only needed if shardTestFiles is true.
       * Default is 1.
       */
      maxInstances: 1,
    },
    {
      browserName: 'MicrosoftEdge',
      version: 'latest',
      platform: 'Windows 10',
      name: 'Edge test test',
      'tunnel-identifier': 'getTunnel'',
      /**
       * If this is set to be true, specs will be sharded by file (i.e. all
       * files to be run by this set of capabilities will run in parallel).
       * Default is false.
       */
      shardTestFiles: true,

      /**
       * Maximum number of browser instances that can run in parallel for this
       * set of capabilities. This is only needed if shardTestFiles is true.
       * Default is 1.
       */
      maxInstances: 1,
    }
  ],
  directConnect: false,
  framework: 'jasmine',
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    browser.baseUrl = 'https://qa1.brandX.com';
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

This only works when I have a set of tests in a single e2e file, that is, app.e2e-spec.ts(For brand X). What if I want to run another set of tests for brandY in brandY.e2e-spec.ts .
How should I set the baseurl for this set of tests? I tried but it always runs the tests on https://qa1.brandX.com

Any Idea about how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just use a local variable

```
// brandX.e2e-spec.ts
let baseUrl = 'https://qa1.brandX.com'

describe('X', () => {

    it('X', async () => {
        await browser.get(baseUrl)
    });
})
```

and

```
// brandY.e2e-spec.ts
let baseUrl = 'https://qa1.brandY.com'

describe('Y', () => {

    it('Y', async () => {
        await browser.get(baseUrl)
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're running your tests, you can pass the base URL as a parameter in your tests.

```
.\node_modules\.bin\protractor --params.baseurl = <url here>
```

And you can call it using

```
await browser.get(browser.params.baseurl);
```

---

OR another approach would be to setup a json file that details your environment configuration. Import that json file and use it

```
const json = require('<path of your json file>');   

await browser.get(json.brandproperties[brandName].baseurl);
```

**json file example**

```
{
 "brandproperties" : {
   "brandX" : {
      "baseurl" : "https://sampleX.com"
   },
   "brandY" : {
      "baseurl" : "https://sampleY.com" 
   }
}
```